# Not getting the meeting link of hangout meeting?

Tags: events, google-api, google-calendar-api, hangouts-api

I have used the the calendar api https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/ for creating an event but not getting meeting link. Also i have tested the api in postman but getting bad request attaching the body

```
resource:{conferenceData:{createRequest:{requestId:7qxalsvy02}}}
conferenceDataVersion: 1
summary: demo14
start: { dateTime: 14/10/2020, timeZone: UTC}
end: { dateTime: 14/10/2020, timeZone: UTC}
attendees: [{email: burhanuddin.hussain@pragtech.co.in, self: True}]
description:des
```

Attaching code

```py
 bearer = 'Bearer '+login_user_id.access_token
            payload = {}
            headers = {
                'Content-Type': "application/json",
                'Authorization':bearer
            }
            
            attendees_list = []
            attendees = self.sudo().partner_ids

            for i in attendees:
                attendees_list.append({"email" :i.email})

            resource={"conferenceData":{"createRequest":{"requestId": "7qxalsvy02"}}}
            body={
                "resource": resource,
                "conferenceDataVersion": 1,
                "summary" : self.name,
                "start": { "dateTime": start_datetime, "timeZone": "UTC"},
                "end": { "dateTime": end_datetime, "timeZone": "UTC"},
                 "attendees":attendees_list,
                 "description":self.description,

            }
            
            data_json = json.dumps(body)
            
            url='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'+login_user_id.calendar_id+'/events'
            
            hangout_meet_response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=data_json)
           
            if hangout_meet_response.status_code == 200:
                data_rec = hangout_meet_response.json()
                
                self.write({"meet_url":data_rec.get('hangoutLink'),"meet_id":data_rec.get('id')})
                hangout_meet_link = data_rec.get('hangoutLink')
                if hangout_meet_link:
                    self.write({"meet_code": hangout_meet_link.split('/')[3]})
            elif hangout_meet_response.status_code == 401:
                raise UserError("Please Authenticate with Hangouts Meet.")
```

Answer (score 0):

### `conferenceDataVersion` is not a part of the request body, it needs to be incorporated into the request URL:

```
url='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'+login_user_id.calendar_id+'/events?conferenceDataVersion=1';


body = {
  "conferenceData":{"createRequest":{"requestId": "7qxalsvy02"}},
  "summary" : self.name,
  "start": { "dateTime": start_datetime, "timeZone": "UTC"},
  "end": { "dateTime": end_datetime, "timeZone": "UTC"},
  "attendees":attendees_list,
  "description":self.description
  }
```

Comment: Made the changes but getting no response

Comment: For testing purposes, test wiht the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) setting the request body to `{
  "conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
      "requestId": "7qxalsvy03"
    }
  },
  "summary": "self.name",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-10-15T10:00:00",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-10-15T15:00:00",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  }
}` and setting `fields` to `hangoutLink`

Comment: Also, see the updated answer skipping the key `resource`.